# How can I avoid special characters in .psql_history file

Tags: linux, postgresql

My .psql_history file has these special characters. `"^A RETURNS text^A LANGUAGE sql^A IMMUTABLE^A"`
What could be causing this? How can I avoid this? It is there in my Ubuntu desktop file, as well as the server machine (SUSE Linux) if I use psql from that one.

Comment: It's a readline history file. It's not meant to be plaintext. Why does this matter?

Comment: When I grep for SQL statements in the history file, the output looks, umm...odd. In fact, it is a bit difficult to read.

Comment: OK. The psql history file isn't intended as a log file. It can be truncated and replaced freely, it doesn't necessarily handle concurrent sessions, etc. If you want a *log file* I suggest enabling logging of statements server-side instead. You can do this per-user, per-database, etc if needed.

Comment: I am not using it as a log file. I grep to get some queries which I executed sometime ago. Anyway, if the file was meant to be like that, it is OK. I thought some setting was making my file have these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. The `.psql_history` file is a readline or libedit history file. It's meant to be fast to search forwards and backwards in when using command-line editing (up arrow, control-R, etc), rather than for human readable use.

Some tools, like `bash`, have a dedicated `history` command that exports a human-readable version of the history. A quick look at the manual shows that `psql`'s is `\s`:

```
craig=> \?
Query Buffer
  ...
  \s [FILE]              display history or save it to file
  ...
```

Note that the `.psql_history` file might not contain all queries, especially if multiple concurrent `psql` sessions are running. It can also be truncated. So it doesn't substitute for a log file, and people looking for actual logging should investigate the server-side query logging settings.